# Is there any Theano function to minimize/optimize an expression?

Tags: python, math, scipy, theano, minimize

Any equivalent function to this one to minimize an expression in 1 line: 
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html

```
sp.optimize.minimize(fun, alpha, method='Newton-CG', jac=True)
```

also tensorflow functions are welcome.